# how to add map marker in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-markers

I am really newbie to angular and was trying to add markers in my map. 
I am stuck. Please consider my question to correct my code; attached.
I found many tutorials and questions about it. Some were complex and rest were not exactly what I need. help required. thanks much

```
var appa = angular.module('appa',['firebase','uiGmapgoogle-maps']);

appa.controller('mainCtrl', function($firebaseObject,$scope) {
  const rootRef =  firebase.database().ref();
  this.object = $firebaseObject(rootRef);

  $scope.map =
  {
    center: {latitude: 51.219053, longitude: 4.404418 },
     zoom: 14,
     myTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
              };
              $scope.markers = [];
              var latLang = new google.maps.LatLng(51.2, 4.404);
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      map : $scope.map,
                      position : latLang,
                      title : 'jhjhjh'
                    });
 $scope.markers.push(marker);
    });
```

```html
<body ng-app="appa">
    <div id="map_canvas" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom">
//sould I add marker here?? and how??
      </ui-gmap-google-map>
      //or somewhere here?
      //sould I add marker here?? and how??
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: `rest were not exactly what I need` so what _do_ you need?

Comment: I need to display a few markers on my map. with different lat and lon. can you help?